# JTextField is locking input

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

I'm using a JTextField (xInput) to input an x coordinate:

```
xInput.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {
          public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                updateX();
              }
              public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                updateX();
              }
              public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                updateX();
              }

              public void updateX() {
                  try {
                      x = Integer.parseInt(xInput.getText().trim());
                  } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
                      if (xInput.getText().equals("")) {
                          x = 0;
                      }
                  }
              }
            });
```

There is also its y counterpart though they're identical (except it uses y obviously) and have the same issue.

What happens is after running the program - which is using Robot for clicking - when you attempt to edit the text field again, the fields are locked, you can click or type on them. I am not using setEditable anywhere. What could be causing this?

Comment: Hi Box. Please replace the code fragment with an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org): a Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example. People cannot debug code with their eyes, they need a runnable program to do that. Do make it short though, cut out all the parts that do not help demonstrating the problem.

Comment: *I'm using a JTextField (xInput) to input an x coordinate:* - maybe you should be using a `JSpinner`?

Comment: Should I use the SSCCE if I have no idea where the problem is coming from?